# jQuery Cycle2 slide disapear when using "fade animation"

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, carousel, cycle2

i've a problem in cycle2 pluging 
when i go to another page and comeback to my page sometimes and not always the slide disappear and show after a sec delay

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow" 
    data-cycle-fx="fadOut" 
    data-cycle-speed="500"
    data-cycle-timeout="3000"
    data-cycle-slides="> div"
>
    <div class="profile-info">
         econtent here
    </div>
   <div class="profile-info">
   content here
   </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow" 
    data-cycle-fx="fadeOut" 
    data-cycle-speed="500"
    data-cycle-timeout="3000"
    data-cycle-slides="> div">

    <div class="profile-info">
       econtent here
    </div>
    <div class="profile-info">
       content here
    </div>
</div>
```

---

### UPDATE

Using [jquery 3.0.0](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js) fix the "Fade Animation Bug"

Comment: Well then I will need more code or informations about.

Comment: it still say in console: Transition "fadOut" not found.  Using fade.

Comment: i uploaded it after change it to fade check it now plz

Comment: everything seems ok, only if you switch tabs in chrome, it somehow reinitializes the slider but believe me its not an error. Slider shows up just  a second after.

Comment: this bug happening only when i use fade animation

Comment: Better inform the plugin developers maybe its a bug.

Comment: check this page for more informations: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/

Comment: thank you , i find out that someone already reported this bug here : https://github.com/malsup/cycle2/issues/790